# Error report when calling a stored procedure

Tags: express, sql-server-2008-r2

Using Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2 Express

I’ve setup a stored procedure that’s been called from a webpage. This stored procedure does an `INSERT` into a table.
Is there a possibility to get an error report or something when the called stored procedure failed on the server side.

Thanks in advance

Called SP

```
USE [TEST]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Web_form]    Script Date: 06/08/2017 12:20:36 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      R H B
-- Create date: 
-- Description: Web form
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Web_form] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @TitleID INT,                       -- WEB 1 to 3 Mr. Ms. Mrs.
    @Forename nvarchar(30)= NULL,       -- WEB
    @Surname  nvarchar(30)= NULL,       -- WEB
    @DateOfBirth nvarchar(30)= NULL,    -- WEB yyyy-mm-dd
    @hHomeEmail nvarchar(30)= NULL,     -- WEB
    @HomeMobile nvarchar(30)= NULL,     -- WEB
    @Sex nvarchar(5)= NULL,             -- WEB M/F
    @HouseNum nvarchar(5)= NULL,        -- WEB
    @Address1 nvarchar(30)= NULL,       -- WEB @HouseNum + @Address1
    @Address2 nvarchar(30)= NULL,       -- WEB
    @Address3 nvarchar(30)= NULL,       -- WEB
    @Address4 nvarchar(30)= NULL,       -- WEB
    @Address5 nvarchar(20)= NULL,       -- WEB Eircode
    @Notes nvarchar(50)= NULL,          -- WEB Comments
    @pPassword nvarchar(20)= NULL,      -- WEB Min 8 char upper lower digit (generate random temp pw)
    @AffiliationStatusID INT,           -- WEB 1=Full 2=OAP 3=Student
    @ConstituencyPrefix nvarchar(20) = NULL,    -- NO defaut (New Online)
    @BranchID INT = 6,              -- 2246 = New Online (Test) - 2247 = New Online (Test)
    @MemberStatusID INT = 6,            -- 1 to 6 Affiliated,Lapsed,Deceased,Withdrawn,Not Affiliated, Incomplete
    @VoteStatusID INT = 2,              -- 1=Voting 2=Non Voting
    @AffiliationDate nvarchar(20)= NULL,            -- GETDATE()
    @DateFirstJoined nvarchar(20)= NULL             -- GETDATE()
    -- @LastUpdate INT                  -- Not in use
AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @MemberNo INT 

 SELECT @MemberNo = MAX(MemberNo)+1 From dbo.member;



 INSERT dbo.member (
        TitleID, 
        Forename, 
        Surname, 
        DateOfBirth, 
        HomeEmail, 
        HomeMobile, 
        Sex, 
        Address1, 
        Address2, 
        Address3, 
        Address4, 
        Address5,
        Notes, 
        AffiliationStatusID,
        ConstituencyPrefix, 
        MemberNo, 
        BranchID,  
        MemberStatusID, 
        VoteStatusID, 
        AffiliationDate, 
        DateFirstJoined
        ) 

    VALUES (
        @TitleID, 
        @Forename, 
        @Surname, 
        @DateOfBirth, 
        @hHomeEmail, 
        @HomeMobile, 
        'U',
        @HouseNum + @Address1, 
        @Address2, 
        @Address3, 
        @Address4, 
        @Address5,
        --CASE @Address5
        --  WHEN '' THEN 'None'
        --  ELSE @Address5
        --  END,
        @Notes,
        @AffiliationStatusID,
        'NO', 
        @MemberNo, 
        2247,  
        1, 
        2, 
        GETDATE(), 
        GETDATE() 
        );  


 SELECT MemberID, 
        ConstituencyPrefix, 
        MemberNo, 
        BranchID, 
        Surname, 
        Forename, 
        TitleID, 
        Address1, 
        Address2, 
        Address3,
        Address4,
        Address5,
        HomeEmail,
        HomeMobile,
        AffiliationDate FROM Member WHERE MemberNo = @MemberNo ;


END
```

Comment: Do you get any exception in the code which calls the stored procedure? Do you mind sharing that code and stored procedure code?

Comment: Updated my question..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Try catch. Create an error table to capture error data. In the catch block write an insert statement to capture the error. You can then create reports from this table.

```
DECLARE @inputParams VARCHAR(max)

SELECT  @inputParams = 'your input variables'

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN Transaction

        DO Something

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK Transaction;--ROLLBACK IN CASE OF ERROR

    INSERT INTO ErrorLog
    VALUES (
        ERROR_NUMBER()
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY()
        ,ERROR_STATE()
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE()
        ,ERROR_LINE()
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ,GETDATE()
        ,@inputParams
        );

    THROW;
END CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT Transaction;
```

Comment: Thanks will try this